# What are some of the impediments to the dismantlement of Obamacare

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, healthcare, affordable-care-act

Seemingly President Trump and a GOP Congress could dismantle Obamacare and replace it with a different solution in a matter of days.  What are some of the nuances that would prevent a rapid replacement?  Of particular importance are the Medicaid expansion (what to do with those new participants) and rebuilding the individual and small-business risk pools and provider networks.  Are there existing estimates on the time it would take to accomplish?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as opinion-based, because "more workable" is very subject to debate.  In *theory*, the new Congress can pass a reform/replacement/repeal bill on January 20th, and Trump can sign it that same day.  But it could take months or years to craft a bill that addresses all the nuances.

Comment: I will rephrase

Comment: You forgot to remove the "more workable" flaimbait. I corrected that for you.

Comment: To be factual, 70% of the co-ops have gone out of business entirely, and the average rate increase this year is over 22% with about 40% of markets with a single provider.  More workable describes the current situation.

Comment: They can't replace it with another solution in a matter of days as they don't have another solution. That aside, the biggest impediment is likely that a lot of people now depend on it for their insurance. And big insurance companies have already invested quite a lot in accommodating it.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest impediment is the 48+ Democrat-aligned members of the Senate.  Any replacement for Obamacare will need to be passed by Congress, and there are two ways that this could be prevented:

1. The easy way is for the senators to [filibuster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filibuster_in_the_United_States_Senate) any bill to replace Obamacare.  It takes 60 senators to override a filibuster, and even if the Republicans win the runoff in Louisiana, they'll only have 52.
2. The hard way is for the Democrats to convince at least two Republican senators to vote with them to directly defeat such a bill.  There are enough anti-Trump Republicans that this isn't as unlikely as you'd expect.

Comment: "The easy way is for the senators to filibuster any bill to replace Obamacare." That won't work as many (but not all) of the provisions can be nullified through the reconciliation process which cannot be filibustered, as the Republicans demonstrated when they passed the Restoring Americans' Healthcare Freedom Reconciliation Act of 2015 for Obama to veto. Once the core provisions are removed, most of the rest of the system will collapse.